# Creating a Shell Element in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am going to write a master's thesis (Mechanical Engineering). I am new to `tikz`, in a sense that I made only 2 `tikz` pictures before. However, I see the huge capabilities and very nice graphical results of `tikz` and want to learn it. I just spend the whole day figuring out how to create a double curved shell element with a reference mid-surface to put in my thesis. This is what I have right now (mostly based on trial & error).

```
\begin{figure}  % aIGAs element
\centering
% Rotation around x-axis and z-axis [70/45]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, tdplot_main_coords]

% Define
\def \thickness {1.0}
\def \materialpointx {0.0}
\def \materialpointy {0.0}
\def \materialpointz {0.0}
\def \shellx {10.0}
\def \shelly {10.0}

% Define shell midsurface corners
\coordinate (midsurf0) at (-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0);
\coordinate (midsurf1) at (+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0);
\coordinate (midsurf2) at (+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0);
\coordinate (midsurf3) at (-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0);
% Define shell topsurface corners
\coordinate (midsurf0t) at (-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,+\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf1t) at (+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,+\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf2t) at (+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,+\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf3t) at (-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,+\thickness/2);

% Define shell bottomsurface corners
\coordinate (midsurf0b) at (-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf1b) at (+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf2b) at (+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf3b) at (-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);

% Define shell midsurface [lower, right, upper, left]
% \tdplotdefinepoints(CenterPoint)(StartPoint)(EndPoint) [x,y,z]
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,-\shelly/2,-8.65)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0)    (+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(+\shellx/2,0,-8.65)(+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0)(+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,+\shelly/2,-8.65)(-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0)(+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(-\shellx/2,0,-8.65)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0)(-        \shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
% Define shell topsurface [lower, right, upper, left]
% \tdplotdefinepoints(CenterPoint)(StartPoint)(EndPoint) [x,y,z]
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,-\shelly/2,-8.65 + \thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-    \shelly/2,\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(+\shellx/2,0,-8.65+\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,-    \shelly/2,\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,+\shelly/2,-8.65+\thickness/2)(-    \shellx/2,+\shelly/2,\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(-\shellx/2,0,-8.65+\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
% Define shell bottmsurface [lower, right, upper, left]
% \tdplotdefinepoints(CenterPoint)(StartPoint)(EndPoint) [x,y,z]
tdplotdefinepoints(0,-\shelly/2,-8.65 - \thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-    \shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(+\shellx/2,0,-8.65-\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,+\shelly/2,-8.65-\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};

\tdplotdefinepoints(-\shellx/2,0,-8.65-\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf0b) -- (midsurf0t);
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf1b) -- (midsurf1t);
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf2b) -- (midsurf2t);
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf3b) -- (midsurf3t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

The shell doesn't look very realistic to me, since the 'back side' would not look the way I have it now. Furthermore, I want to fill the mid-surface (gray). I searched very well on Google, but am unable to find anything on this. When the shell is ready I only need to place some vectors in it (tangent to the surface at some point).
Another tricky part is that I need curvilinear coordinates that match exactly with the boundary of the shell, but I have really no idea how to get this nicely working.

Does anyone know how to do this? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! I'll keep that in mind. I use a documentclass of my University, which requires many other packages and therefore I didn't include that in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of this answer is twofold. In the first part, I cleaned up your code a bit such that it runs through. The second part is an attempt to convince you to make yourself familiar with yet another package: `pgfplots`. This is because it has some shaders built in, which are pretty good (as long as you don't compare them to asymptote ;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% Rotation around x-axis and z-axis [70/45]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, tdplot_main_coords]

% Define
\def\thickness{1.0}
\def\materialpointx{0.0}
\def\materialpointy{0.0}
\def\materialpointz{0.0}
\def\shellx{10.0}
\def\shelly{10.0}

% Define shell midsurface corners
\coordinate (midsurf0) at (-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0);
\coordinate (midsurf1) at (\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0); %removed leading + signs
\coordinate (midsurf2) at (\shellx/2,\shelly/2,0); %removed leading + signs
\coordinate (midsurf3) at (-\shellx/2,\shelly/2,0);%removed leading + signs 
% Define shell topsurface corners
\coordinate (midsurf0t) at (-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,+\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf1t) at (\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\coordinate (midsurf2t) at (\shellx/2,\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\coordinate (midsurf3t) at (-\shellx/2,\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs

% Define shell bottomsurface corners
\coordinate (midsurf0b) at (-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf1b) at (+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf2b) at (+\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\coordinate (midsurf3b) at (-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);

% Define shell midsurface [lower, right, upper, left]
% \tdplotdefinepoints(CenterPoint)(StartPoint)(EndPoint) [x,y,z]
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,-\shelly/2,-8.65)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0)(\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(\shellx/2,0,-8.65)(+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0)(\shellx/2,\shelly/2,0);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,\shelly/2,-8.65)(-\shellx/2,+\shelly/2,0)(\shellx/2,\shelly/2,0);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(-\shellx/2,0,-8.65)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,0)(-\shellx/2,\shelly/2,0);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thick]{10}{}{};
% Define shell topsurface [lower, right, upper, left]
% \tdplotdefinepoints(CenterPoint)(StartPoint)(EndPoint) [x,y,z]
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,-\shelly/2,-8.65 + \thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-    \shelly/2,\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(+\shellx/2,0,-8.65+\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,-    \shelly/2,\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,+\shelly/2,-8.65+\thickness/2)(-    \shellx/2,\shelly/2,\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(-\shellx/2,0,-8.65+\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,\shelly/2,\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
% Define shell bottmsurface [lower, right, upper, left]
% \tdplotdefinepoints(CenterPoint)(StartPoint)(EndPoint) [x,y,z]
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,-\shelly/2,-8.65 - \thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-    \shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(+\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(+\shellx/2,0,-8.65-\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,+\shelly/2,-8.65-\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,\shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(\shellx/2,\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};

\tdplotdefinepoints(-\shellx/2,0,-8.65-\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,-\shelly/2,-\thickness/2)(-\shellx/2,\shelly/2,-\thickness/2);%removed leading + signs
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[black,ultra thin]{10}{}{};
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf0b) -- (midsurf0t);
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf1b) -- (midsurf1t);
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf2b) -- (midsurf2t);
\draw[black, ultra thin] (midsurf3b) -- (midsurf3t);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={myblackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0.6); gray(1cm)=(0.8)}
,width=12cm,compat=1.15,view={0}{10}} % notice that because of the redefinition
% of xscale and yscale below the view angle does not have its original meaning
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x,\y)=-(0.3*(\x-2)*(\x-2));}}
\tikzset{declare function={g(\x,\y)=-(0.3*(\x-10)*(\x-10)+0.3*64);}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1,xscale=1.2,opacity=0.7] 
\begin{axis}[samples=50,hide axis,shader=interp]
    \path (10,0,0) -- (10,10,0);
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=-10:0] [surf] {f(-x,y)};
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=0:10] [surf] {f(x,y)};
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=-10:0,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{f(-\x,0)});
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=0:10,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{f(\x,0)});
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=-10:0] [surf] {g(-x,y)};
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=0:10] [surf] {g(x,y)};
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=-10:0,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{g(-\x,0)});
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=0:10,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{g(\x,0)});
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Your code (after some minor cleaning):
[image]

With pgfplots:
[image]

I honestly do not know how to reproduce these shadings in Ti*k*Z without `pgfplots` in a straightforward way.

**EDIT**: A single arc is much simpler, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={myblackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0.4); gray(1cm)=(0.8)}
,width=12cm,compat=1.15,view={0}{10}} % notice that because of the redefinition
% of xscale and yscale below the view angle does not have its original meaning
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x,\y)=-(0.3*0.64*(\x)*(\x));}}
\tikzset{declare function={g(\x,\y)=-(0.3*(\x-10)*(\x-10)+0.3*64);}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1,xscale=1.2,opacity=0.7] 
\begin{axis}[hide axis,shader=interp]
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=-10:10] [surf] {f(x,y)};
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=-10:10,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{f(\x,0)});
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=-10:0] [surf] {g(-x,y)};
    \addplot3[domain y=0:1,domain=0:10] [surf] {g(x,y)};
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=-10:0,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{g(-\x,0)});
    \addplot3[very thick,domain=0:10,samples y=0] ({\x},0.5,{g(\x,0)});
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will look in to the pgfplots package for sure. I am really confused when I see many tikzpictures in 3D, while they aren't made with the tikz-3d package. How can they get that 3D look and isn't that a better option then?

Comment: Your picture allready looks much better than what I managed to get out of it. However, would there be a possibility to make a single arc instead of the 2 arcs with a kink in-between? I will try to shade the middle surface (area within the black lines) myself :) Thank you

Comment: @LeimacSmada I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Do you want to replace the upper contour by a single arc? Or are you just worried about the tiny white gap in the middle of the upper contour?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in that one. Indeed I want to replace it with a single arc since this kink is in reality not visible behind the curved top surface.